# How to handle Firefox binary default location?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

After some system updates I'm not able to run `webdriver` with `Firefox` using

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

I get following exception:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: 
Message: 
    Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, 
    no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, 
    and no binary flag set on the command line
```

so I'm wondering what is this `default location` and, more important, where it defined (script name) so I can set new value or use existed to copy binary into it? I used debugger in `PyCharm` to find some tips, but with no luck...

Currently `Firefox` installed into `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox`

P.S. I know that I can use `Firefox Profile`, `FirefoxBinary`, specify path to `geckodriver.exe` etc, but I'm not searching for this kind of solution

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20950748/cannot-find-firefox-binary-in-path-make-sure-firefox-is-installed

Comment: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver#important-system-properties

Answer (score 2):

By default selenium will look into the path - C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\

Please uninstall older one and install firefox using the link - http://filehippo.com/download_firefox/67599/

you can also look into - [Setting path to firefox binary on windows with selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25713824/setting-path-to-firefox-binary-on-windows-with-selenium-webdriver)