# Selenium Firefox webdriver via geckodriver results in error: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I'm using Selenium like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

firefox_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True

browser = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=firefox_capabilities)

# Set screen resolution to 1366 x 768 like most 15" laptops
display = Display(visible=0, size=(1366, 768))
display.start()


# Sets the width and height of the current window
browser.set_window_size(1366, 768)

# Open the URL
browser.get('http://www.vionblog.com/')

# set timeouts
browser.set_script_timeout(30)
browser.set_page_load_timeout(30) # seconds

# Take screenshot
browser.save_screenshot('vionblog.png')

# quit browser
browser.quit()

# quit Xvfb display
display.stop()
```

But when I run the script, I get the following error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   
>   File "a.py", line 10, in <module>
>     browser = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=firefox_capabilities)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 145, in __init__
>     self.service.start()
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 81, in start
>     os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message) 
> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
> ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium using Python - Geckodriver executable needs to be in PATH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your error message

```
Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

we can understand that the problem is that Selenium couldn't locate the geckodriver executable.

You have 2 solutions:

1. [Add geckodriver.exe path to your PATH variable environment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40208762/3846228)
2. [Inform the geckodriver.exe path when starting the webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25715497/3846228)