# Selenium Python - Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium

I am using selenium to crawl a javascript website, the issue is that, a Firefox browser opens up, but the call for the URL is not done. however, when I close the browser, it is then that call for URL is done and of course I get the missing driver exception. what do you think the issue comes from.

knowing that:

- all programs are up-to-date
- my solution works fine, in local, but when I try to deploy it on the server, I start having issues

Example: at my local machine, I run this script and everything goes smooth, however when I run it a server (Linux), only the browser opens up and no get URL is called

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

geckodriver_path = r'.../geckodriver'

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path= geckodriver_path)
time.sleep(3)
driver.get("http://www.stackoverflow.com")
```

Comment: please add your exception log.

Comment: the exception is not important because it is me who generate it when i close the browser: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 0

Comment: my question is more about why the browser remains open without passing the part where the call for url will be done

Comment: Please include a [mcve] that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I end up finding the solution :

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

geckodriver_path = r'/path_to/geckodriver'

binary = FirefoxBinary(r'/usr/bin/firefox')

capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
capabilities["marionette"] = False

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary,
                           executable_path= geckodriver_path,
                           capabilities=capabilities)

time.sleep(3)
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
time.sleep(6)
driver.close()

# solution from: 
# https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3884
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25713824/setting-path-to-firefox-binary-on-windows-with-selenium-webdriver
```