# How to open Firefox Developer Edition through Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, firefox-developer-edition

Following some tutorials on Selenium, I installed the `geckodriver`. In order to run a simple code on python to run Selenium, I have to specify this path in the command line:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/xx/Downloads/geckodriver-v0.24.0-linux64
```

But I want Selenium to open the Developer edition I have as it contains the extension  I want to test:
When I sepcify the path for the Developer edition executable:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/xx/Documents/ff_extension/firefox/
```

Then run my python script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Selenium still opens the `geckodriver` browser.

Q: How can I instruct Selenium to run Firefox Dev. Edition in the path I specify?

Answer (score 2):

The **Firefox Developer Edition** browser is not installed at the conventional location where regular **Firefox** browser gets installed. In my *Windows 8* box *Firefox Developer Edition* browser got installed within the directory:

```
C:\Program Files\Firefox Developer Edition
```

Now, while invoking *Firefox Developer Edition* browser you need to pass the *absolute path* of the *Firefox Developer Edition binary* through the argument **`firefox_binary`** as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

  firefox_dev_binary = FirefoxBinary(r'C:\Program Files\Firefox Developer Edition\firefox.exe')
  driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=firefox_dev_binary, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://www.google.co.in')
  print("Page Title is : %s" %driver.title)
  # driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Page Title is : Google
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: Firefox-DeveloperEdition]

---

### This usecase

As you are on *Linux* you need to provide the *absolute* path of:

- *Firefox Developer Edition* binary
- *GeckoDriver* binary

So your effective code block will be:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

firefox_dev_binary = FirefoxBinary('/path/to/Firefox Developer Edition/firefox')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=firefox_dev_binary, executable_path='/home/xx/Downloads/geckodriver-v0.24.0-linux64/geckodriver')
driver.get('https://www.google.co.in')
print("Page Title is : %s" %driver.title)
# driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FirefoxBinary` as described here:
[Setting path to firefox binary on windows with selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25713824/setting-path-to-firefox-binary-on-windows-with-selenium-webdriver)

> To set the custom path to Firefox you need to use FirefoxBinary:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary('F:\FirefoxPortable\Firefox.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions

s = FirefoxOptions()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=s)
```