# Selenium geckodriver opens Firefox developer edition and not normal edition

Tags: selenium, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm using pytest framework and selenium to test my code.

```
Firefox.__init__(self, executable_path=geckodriver_path, firefox_profile=self.profile, service_log_path=common_strings.geckodriver_log_path)
```

I find only solutions on how to make Selenium open developer edition instead of the normal edition but in my case, I want the opposite.
For some reason, Selenium opens the developer edition and I actually need the normal edition to test my code.

Any suggestions or thoughts why it happens?

Comment: Where did you find _to make Selenium open developer edition instead of the normal edition_?

Comment: @DebanjanB https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54754686/how-to-open-firefox-developer-edition-through-selenium

Comment: When I manually change the key "PathToExe" in the registry of Mozilla to the path of the normal edition of FF, Selenium opens the normal edition as expected. of course, this solution is very dirty and I've tried it just to test my code. I don't understand what makes Selenium open the FF Developer Edition. any idea? I also tried to remove the developer edition but in this case, it doesn't help and I'm thrown out of the test.