# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Failed to find firefox binary. You can set it by specifying the path to 'firefox_binary'

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, firefox, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I want to know how to use selenium.
to scrape dynamic page.
Is there some relation to installing Firefox?

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Firefox()

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Failed to find firefox binary. You can set it by specifying the path to 'firefox_binary':

from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary('/path/to/binary')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
```

Comment: [Check this tutorial](https://www.guru99.com/selenium-python.html). And yes, you will need the Browser that you intend to use. Because the Selenium only controls it

Comment: I use edge so I changed to                                                                   "driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path='C:\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe') "     but        "os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'MicrosoftWebDriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please download from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=619687"

Comment: @AtsushiSakata Please don't change the question once you have received well researched answers else the working answers will become invalid and won't be useful to future readers. If your requirement have changed feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirement. Stack Overflow contributors will be happy to help you out. As of now I have reverted the question to it's original state.

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Failed to find firefox binary. You can set it by specifying the path to 'firefox_binary':
```

...implies that the **GeckoDriver** was unable to find the **firefox** binary.

Perhaps *Firefox* browser is installed in a non-conventional location on your machine so *GeckoDriver* is unable to find it.

---

### Solution

Incase *Firefox* is installed in a non-conventional location on your machine you need to pass the *absolute location* of the *firefox binary* as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver

binary = '/path/to/firefox'
# Example of using Firefox Developer Edition on Windows OS
# binary = r'C:\Program Files\Firefox Developer Edition\firefox.exe'
# Example of using Firefox Nightly Edition on Windows OS
# binary = r'C:\Program Files\Nightly\firefox.exe'

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.binary = binary
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, executable_path='/path/to/geckodriver')
browser.get('http://google.com/')
browser.quit()
```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to open Firefox Developer Edition through Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54754686/how-to-open-firefox-developer-edition-through-selenium/54762442#54762442)

Comment: but this error     os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

Comment: Provide the _absolute path_ of **GeckoDriver** in place of `/path/to/geckodriver`. You already know where you have downloaded and extracted it.

Comment: then this Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities

Comment: There is a mismatch in the _GeckoDriver_, _Firefox_ and _Selenium_ versions. See: [selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities with GeckoDriver, Selenium and Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52002958/selenium-common-exceptions-sessionnotcreatedexception-message-unable-to-find-a/52006033#52006033)

Comment: but still caps I changed the content

Comment: If your requirement have changed feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirement. Stack Overflow contributors will be happy to help you out.