# Tor crashes everytime i try to start it with selenium, Python: Please don't delete my question, the other question has only an answer in C#

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Every time I want to run my Program Tor crashes. The Code has no errors. And the Paths are all correct. Here is my Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
import os

torexe = os.popen(r'C:/Users/Seya Fässler/Desktop/Tor Browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Tor/tor.exe')
profile = FirefoxProfile(r'C:/Users/Seya Fässler/Desktop/Tor Browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Browser/profile.default')
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', '127.0.0.1')
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', 9050)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_remote_dns", False)
profile.update_preferences()


firefox_options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
firefox_options.binary_location = r'C:/Users/Seya Fässler/Desktop/Tor Browser/Browser/firefox.exe'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile= profile, options = firefox_options, executable_path=r'C:/Users/Seya Fässler/Webdrivers/geckodriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.apple.com")
```

After that, it shows up this Alert:

[image: Tor Alert]

When I press OK it opens this window and I can't copy the log, because it has 0 lines.

[image: Tor Alert 2]

I use Windows 10, as an environment I use anaconda, the tor browser is on the newest version (9.5.3) and I use Python 3.8.3.
**Please don't delete my question because of duplicates, the other question has an answer but only in C#, and it doesn't work with python!**
Thanks!

Comment: There is absolutely no use in raising the same question and deleting it again and again. Instead edit the first question with all the required info and send a message to the contributor who have closed the other question appending `@` before the username, so your question can be `ReOpened`

Comment: Ok, i will do that. How can i see who has closed my question. And another question on your Post somebody has answered in C#, do you have the code in Python?

Comment: I have added another dup target of a working and accepted answer. Let me know if that address your question.

Comment: @DebanjanB It starts Firefox not tor. It doesn't work

Comment: [TOR](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/21383/what-is-the-difference-between-the-tor-browser-initiated-by-firefox-v68-9-0esr-a) project can be implemented using either of the of the _Browsing Contexts_ e.g. _Firefox_, _Firefox Nightly_, _Chrome_, _Brave_ depending on your requirement. The default manual implementation is through _Firefox ESR_ which isn't compatible with WebDriver specs. Hence the error.

Comment: @DebanjanB Ok, thanks! What would you choose?

Comment: Well, I'm all over. As a contributor to [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329528/which-firefox-browser-versions-supported-for-given-geckodriver-version/45331403#45331403) and production environment is concerned, I use [Mozilla Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329528/which-firefox-browser-versions-supported-for-given-geckodriver-version/45331403#45331403) as that's well maintained.

Comment: @DebanjanB and have you an working example? With tor implementation and Firefox, Python

Comment: As a contributor to [Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329528/which-firefox-browser-versions-supported-for-given-geckodriver-version/45331403#45331403) for research and development, I use [Firefox Developer Edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54754686/how-to-open-firefox-developer-edition-through-selenium/54762442#54762442) or _Firefox Nightly_.

Comment: @DebanjanB Thanks for your Help, it was really helpful. But do you have an tutorial how i can implement Tor in Firefox

Comment: Doesn't [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53942553/how-to-connect-to-tor-browser-using-python) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62666075/how-to-initiate-a-tor-browser-9-5-which-uses-the-default-firefox-to-68-9-0esr-us) solution works for you using _Mozilla Firefox_ and _Firefox Nightly_?

Comment: @DebanjanB it has this error and opens nothing: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Acces denied (os error 5) and im pretty sure that the paths are correct