# Using FireFox Driver (geckodriver)

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, pycharm, geckodriver

Here's my code

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox('C:\\Users\\ojadi\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.26.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe')
browser.get('https://www.google.co.uk/')
```

Here is the error i keep getting

```
The directory name is invalid: 'C:\\Users\\ojadi\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.26.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe'
```

This is where I put the driver

> C:\Users\ojadi\Downloads\geckodriver-v0.26.0-win64

Please help me,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting path to firefox binary on windows with selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25713824/setting-path-to-firefox-binary-on-windows-with-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 2):

The first, unnamed parameter when using [`webdriver.Firefox()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_firefox/selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.html#module-selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver) is `firefox_profile`, which takes either a `FirefoxProfile` object or a string. If it's a string, you're telling the Python language bindings what directory you want to use as the template for the anonymous profile used when launching Firefox.

Other answers may have you attempting to use the `firefox_binary` argument. This is incorrect, as that is the argument specifying the path to the *Firefox* binary, not the *geckodriver* binary.

The argument you actually want to use is `executable_path`, which is the argument that refers to the location of the `geckodriver` binary. To wit, you want something like the following:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='C:\\Users\\ojadi\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.26.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe')
```

Now, if you also need to specify a path to a specific Firefox binary installation, you can specify both `firefox_binary` and `executable_path`.

Answer (score 0):

try to replace your line with this one bellow:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox(r'C:\Users\ojadi\Downloads\geckodriver-v0.26.0-win64\geckodriver.exe')
```

Comment: still doesn't work, it says      NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'C:\\Users\\ojadi\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.26.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe'

Comment: you are using windows or linux?

Comment: try first of all,  to put the file in the same location of the .py file, then change the line to be: browser = webdriver.Firefox('geckodriver.exe')

Answer (score 0):

I just ran this code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Selenium\geckodriver.exe')
driver.set_page_load_timeout(60)
driver.get("https://www.msnbc.com/")

continue_link = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
for elem in elems:
    print(elem.get_attribute("href"))
```

I got this result.

```
https://www.msnbc.com/
https://www.msnbc.com/listen
https://www.msnbc.com/live
https://www.nbcnews.com/
https://www.today.com/
https://www.msnbc.com/
https://www.msnbc.com/rachel-maddow-show
https://www.msnbc.com/morning-joe
https://www.msnbc.com/deadline-white-house
https://www.msnbc.com/mtp-daily
https://www.msnbc.com/the-beat-with-ari-melber
https://www.msnbc.com/all

etc., etc., etc.

https://www.msnbc.com/
https://www.nbcnews.com/pages/about-nbc-news-digital
https://www.msnbc.com/help
https://www.nbcunicareers.com/
https://www.msnbcstore.com/?cid=MSNBCSTRE
https://www.nbcuniversal.com/privacy/?brandA=MSNBC&intake=MSNBC
https://www.nbcuniversal.com/privacy/notrtoo/?brandA=MSNBC&intake=MSNBC
https://www.msnbc.com/terms-of-service
https://www.msnbc.com/closed-captioning
https://www.msnbc.com/transcripts
https://www.msnbc.com/advertising-and-partnerships
http://info.evidon.com/pub_info/1196?v=1
https://www.nbcnews.com/
https://www.msnbc.com/
https://www.today.com/
```

Make sure you download the appropriate (32-bit or 64-bit) geckodriver from the link below.

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases